# Limit packets per minute per IP address

Tags: linux, limit, iptables

Only using IPTABLES, how would you limit requests (pings for example) from the same Internet host to x number of packets per minute, say 5 for simplicity sake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iptables -A INPUT -p ICMP -m limit --limit 5/minute --limit-burst 5 -j ACCEPT`

`-m limit`: This uses the limit iptables extension

`–limit 5/minute`: This limits only maximum of 5 connection per minute. Change this value based on your specific requirement

`–limit-burst 5`: This value indicates that the limit/minute will be enforced only after the total number of connection have reached the limit-burst level.

The above should do the trick!

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to work on my xubuntu box (not that I need it, but it looked cool).